# Параметры для Makefile для nasm

Tags: makefile, nasm

При попытке скомпилировать проект на nasm через Makefile, мне выдается такая ошибка, прощу подскажите как исправить.
Cтроение проекта:

```
Project
    |->src-.
    |      |->main.asm
    |      '->io.inc
    |->obj
    '->Makefile
```

Содержимое Makefile:

```
PREF_SRC_ASM = ./src/
PREF_OBJ = ./obj/

ASM = nasm
ASM_FLAGS = -f win64

SRC_ASM = $(wildcard $(PREF_SRC_ASM)*.asm)
OBJ_ASM = $(patsubst $(PREF_SRC_ASM)%.asm, $(PREF_OBJ)%.obj, $(SRC_ASM))

build: $(OBJ_ASM)

$(PREF_OBJ)%.obj : $(PREF_SRC_ASM)%.asm
    $(ASM) $(ASM_FLAGS) $< -o $@
```

выводится ошибка:

```
src/main.asm:4: error: unable to open include file `io.inc': No such file or directory
```

что нужно прописать в Makefile что бы nasm увидел файл io.inc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел ответ в документации nasm "2.1.6 Ключ -i: Каталоги поиска включаемых файлов"
добавил код:

```
$(ASM) -ic:$(PREF_SRC_ASM) $(ASM_FLAGS) $< -o $@
```

так же об этом говорится сдесь https://translated.turbopages.org/proxy_u/en-ru.ru.e7ea6136-639207e7-832c9807-74722d776562/https/stackoverflow.com/a/18079206